# Why didn't they make series for Tom and Jerry from the start?

Tags: tom-and-jerry

Every *Tom and Jerry* episode is self-contained. But why didn't they make continuous series from the start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because Tom and Jerry wasn't created for Television, they were short movies intended for movie theaters, to accompany a main feature film. They were first produced long before television ownership was common.

With such a format, a continuous series with an evolving plot and character arcs are not as convenient, as not everyone is going to see the same movies or in the same order.

Even later when television was more common, the format for these characters was already established.

As others have pointed out there were serialized shorter movies like Flash Gordon, but it remains the point that it is a reasonable decision to make each Tom & Jerry movie independent for the purpose of not requiring your audience to have seen previous installments.

[Also, why *should* they be expected to make a continuous series? That is a creative decision. Similar short non-serialized movies are made today]

Comment: But they were making serials that were exclusively shown in theatres [way before](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_film_serials) the early Tom and Jerry cartoons - shows like Flash Gordon.

Comment: That's a fair point @HorusKol .... and Flash Gordon serials were shown typically on Saturday afternoon childrens matinees, and I guess designed to hook kids into coming back every week.  B

Comment: But I think that its still a fair point that its not a perfect medium to present serial material, especially to adults.

Answer (score 2):

Tom and Jerry were expensive to make (about [$50,000 an episode](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_and_Jerry#:%7E:text=Barbera%20estimated%20the%20typical%20budget,work%20with%20a%20script%20beforehand.), and also required a lot of work from a small group of people to draw every frame. Only 140 or so Tom and Jerry shorts were produced in the first 18 years, with many months between each new release.

On the other hand, film serials would generally cost about $10,000 an episode. Even the most extravagant shows like Buck Rogers or Flash Gordon with their special effects would cost only about [$30,000 an episode](https://www.loc.gov/static/programs/national-film-preservation-board/documents/flash_gordon.pdf).

Production would have been a lot faster (actors can act faster than animators can draw), so it would have been easier for the studio to create the 8 to 15 episodes they would then release each week to the cinemas.

Comment: +1 fair points.  I think that its still somewhat the case that the movie theatre is less convenient than TV for serialized material.  Low budget serials aimed at a specific market, like Saturday Matinees for children does enable that content more easily viable for movie theaters.